# Apache SOLR: Most Recent & Relevant Documents should be on TOP

Tags: apache, solr, solr-boost

I have articles indexed as documents in APACHE SOLR.

When I query SOLR with search term for example "patient access", the documents come are sorted on score by default. But my requirement is to have recent documents boosted as well if there is a document with complete phrase match in title of the content and is old document, it should appear on top as well.

I have tried using bf=recip(ms(NOW,modify_date),3.16e-11,1,1) for recent documents boosting, but I need to know how can I handle, recency as well as relevancy together.

In short if complete phrase is matched score gets more boost as well as recent documents get boost also.

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to weight those factors against each other - look at your `debugQuery` output to see how much each term affect the score, and tune the values - for recip this is the third parameter (above the `/`).

Comment: so, did you try it and it's not working for you?

Comment: no actually I used, my own custom score logic. which helped as requirements got a little bit changed. thought thanks a lot :)